# Problem with code in Sharepoint/Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, power-automate

So here's my problem, 
We want to automate the copy of notepad (Sharepoint) in my company,
We already have the power-automate script which allows us to copy links from sharepoint sites,
And here is the Power shell code which allows you to recover the site files and copy them to another:

```
$SiteURL = "https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/********"
$TargetFolderURL = "/sites/*********/*****"
$SitestoCopy = "copy"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $SitestoCopy

Write-Host "Nombre total d'éléments :" $items.Count

ForEach ($item in $items) 
{
    Write-Host $item["Title"]

    #Copy All Files and Folders from one folder to another
    Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl $item["Title"] -TargetUrl $TargetFolderURL -SkipSourceFolderName -Force

}
```

I have an error : Copy-PnPFile : File not found.

i have no clue to resolve this problem,
Anyone could help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the -SourceUrl param. You pass the item Title. According [to the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/copy-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps) this should be the relative url to the item. I am not sure now in what column it was stored I am guessing something like "ServerRelativeUrl" or "FileRef". Please try to check it out and change it to correct column to pass the url to the item not the title.

I hope it will be of any help :)

Answer (score 0):

SourceUrl should be the file server relative url, use FileRef instead,
TargetUrl should be TargetFolderURL +filename

Modify the code snippet as below:

```
$SiteURL = "https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"
$TargetFolderURL = "/sites/dev/docs/"
$SitestoCopy = "copy"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $SitestoCopy

Write-Host "Nombre total d'éléments :" $items.Count

ForEach ($item in $items) 
{

    $TargetFileUrl=$TargetFolderURL+$item["FileLeafRef"]
    #Copy All Files and Folders from one folder to another
    Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl $item["FileRef"] -TargetUrl $TargetFileUrl -SkipSourceFolderName -Force

}
```

Comment: Thank you !! i don't have error message anymore, but still it's copying a uknow files, not all the files that i want,
Is it possible to copy a OneNote file from the content site with this method ?

Comment: Yes, just now, I tested to copy a OneNote file with ".one" file extension, it's working as expected. In your side, if you are copying unknow files, checking about $TargetFileUrl to see if it's valid file path with file extension name.

Comment: Thank you again,
i'm trying to use the same code as yours, but in the target folder : i have this type of files : "target01.000
I don't know why i have this .000

Comment: What did you get from $TargetFolderURL+$item["FileLeafRef"], please use Write-Host to output and check.

Comment: if i use Write-Host i get for every single site:
/sites/********/docs+Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem[FileLeafRef]

Comment: Seems you are missing "" for FileLeafRef, it should output the file relative url as the result.

Comment: Hello again !
The "" where in the code : write-Host $TargetFolderURL+$item["FileLeafRef"].
The files in the target folder are still an unknown files with (.000) and it seems to copying one file per sites, i really don't know why..

Comment: /sites/********/docs+Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem[FileLeafRef] to /sites/********/docs+Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem["FileLeafRef"]